# Android start service issue in onCreate of Activity

Tags: android, service, android-activity, oncreate

I have tried to start a service and bind to the service in my Activity's `onCreate()` method. When I try to call a function from service like `commSessionManagerService.startCommandUpperM()` afterwards, a `NullPointerException` occurs. Here is the code that I use to start the service and bind to it:

```
    Intent startIntent = new Intent(this, CommSessionManagerService.class);
    startService(startIntent);
    Intent bindIntent = new Intent(this, CommSessionManagerService.class);
    bindService(bindIntent, conn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

If I move the function `startCommandUpperM()` to `onStartCommand()` in the `CommSessionManagerService`, the `onCreate` method will take several seconds to complete. As a related note, I have a created and started a thread in the `startCommandUpperM()` function.

Comment: Please post more code. When exactly do you call `startCommandUpperM();`? Does your Binder work?

Comment: in startCommandUpperM, the code just like as below:        csThread = new CommSessionThread(this);    csThread.start();   and in CommSessionThread ( public void run() {
  while(runningFlag)
  {
   switch(commSession.getSessionState())
   {
    case PsmConstants.STATE_TRANSMIT:
     commSession.transmit();
     break;
    case PsmConstants.STATE_RECEIVE:
     commSession.receive();
     break;
    case PsmConstants.STATE_SUSPEND:
     break;
    case PsmConstants.STATE_IDLE:
     break;

    default:
     break;}
  }
 })

Comment: Are you returning itself CommSessionManagerService's object in onBind() in service ? Please post onBind() code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your `Service` is actually bound on the UiThread. As `onCreate` also runs on UiThread, your call to `bindService` result in `Handler.post(Runnable)` be called on the main thread's handler.

So when `bindService` returns, the `Service` isn't already bound.
To circumvent this problem, you should put your code using your Service inside `ServiceConnection.onServiceConnected()`.

Comment: Thanks :), it works well, but now the onCreate method will take several seconds when i put startCommandUpperM in onServiceConnected, i have a thread created and start in startCommandUpperM, is that ok?

Comment: I think it's pretty ok =)