# Android - Starting a service in the onCreate method of activity with some delay

Tags: android, multithreading, service

First of all I've seen this:
[Android start service issue in onCreate of Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21881617/android-start-service-issue-in-oncreate-of-activity)

However my question is different.

I want to create an activity, then after couple seconds, a service should start automatically (I don't want the user press any button to start service) and when the user pressed a button the service should be stopped.

If I call the startservice in oncreate method, the service will start before the completing of activity creation.

If I use runnable, to define service, I would not have any direct access to service to stop it.

I tried to use  new Thread(), and start service in the run function and then start the thread, but it didn't worked for me too.

So how should I do?

Thanks.

Comment: i dont get this "__If I use runnable, to define service, I would not have any direct access to service to stop it__"

Answer (score 1):

to stop your service with a button click

```
stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            stopService(new Intent(context,serviceclass));
        }
    });
```

to start it after a delay

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                startService(new Intent(context,serviceclass));
            }
        }, 3000); // 3 seconds..
```

Comment: The problem is that where exactly I should start the service? when I start it in onCreate method of activity, the service blocks the activity because it starts before the onCreate method runs completely.

Comment: then start it when you are done with all important things..anywhere.. your service runs on the ui thread, so the activity is being blocked because you doing a lot of stuff on the main thread.. so re-structure your codes@Taher